# Nav buttons that take you to pages not new windows of said pages

Tags: java, html, css, hyperlink, nav

I am trying to make my top nav buttons direct the user to the appropriate page in the same window and currently its not doing that. Currently when the user clicks said button, a new window or tab is opened instead of the action happening in the current window.

```
<body>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="top_block topNav">
   <div class="content">
    <div id="topButtons">
     <div id="topLogo" class="logo">
      <div class="innerLogo">
       <img id="clickLogo" src="images/####Logo160x50.png" title="####">
      </div>
     </div>
     <img id="clickMenu" src="images/btnMenu.png" title="Menu">
     <a href="file:^px/Home.px" target="mc"><img id="clickHome" src="images/btnHome.png" title="Home"></a>
     <a href="file:^px/Alarms.px" target="mc"><img id="clickAlarm" src="images/btnAlarm.png" title="Alarm Console"></a>
     <a href="" target="mc"><img id="clickSched" src="images/btnClock.png" title="Schedule"></a>
     <a href="" target="mc"><img id="clickCal" src="images/btnSchedule.png" title="Calendar"></a>
     <a href="history:" target="mc"><img id="clickChart" src="images/btnChart.png" title="Chart Builder"></a>
     <a href="/logout"><img id="clickLogout" src="images/btnLogout.png" title="Logout"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="background topRightPane">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set the `target` attribute (incorrectly). The default value for target is `_self`, which is what you actually want and in that case you can also remove the whole attribute from the link.

```
<a href="file:^px/Home.px"><img id="clickHome" src="images/btnHome.png" title="Home"></a>
```

or also correct

```
<a href="file:^px/Home.px" target="_self"><img id="clickHome" src="images/btnHome.png" title="Home"></a>
```

The target attribute specifies where to open the linked document:

> `_blank` - opens the linked document in a new window or tab
>
> `_self` - opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)
>
> `_parent` - opens the linked document in the parent frame
>
> `_top` - opens the linked document in the full body of the window
>
> `framename` opens the linked document in the named iframe/window

Read more about the target attribute:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a?retiredLocale=de#attributes
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp